# MSIL : Superfluous branch

Tags: cil

Consider this C# snippet:

```
static string input = null;
static string output = null;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     input = "input";
     output = CallMe(input);
}

public static string CallMe(string input)
{
     output = "output";
     return output;
}
```

Dissassembling using Reflector shows:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
    {
        .entrypoint
        .maxstack 8
        L_0000: nop 
        L_0001: ldstr "input"
        L_0006: stsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::input
        L_000b: ldsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::input
        L_0010: call string Reflector_Test.Program::CallMe(string)
        L_0015: stsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::output
        L_001a: ret 
    }

 .method public hidebysig static string CallMe(string input) cil managed
    {
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] string CS$1$0000)
        L_0000: nop 
        L_0001: ldstr "output"
        L_0006: stsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::output
        L_000b: ldsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::output
        L_0010: stloc.0 
        L_0011: br.s L_0013
        L_0013: ldloc.0 
        L_0014: ret 
    }
```

The piece that puzzles me is:

```
L_0010: stloc.0 
L_0011: br.s L_0013
L_0013: ldloc.0
```

It stores the item, branches to the next line (which would have been executed anyway) and then loads it again.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This only happens in Debug, not in Release. I suspect its to assist during debugging. It perhaps allows you to chuck breakpoints mid statement and see the return value.

Note the release version has much more concise IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldstr "input"
    L_0005: stsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::input
    L_000a: ldsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::input
    L_000f: call string Reflector_Test.Program::CallMe(string)
    L_0014: stsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::output
    L_0019: ret 
}




.method public hidebysig static string CallMe(string input) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldstr "output"
    L_0005: stsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::output
    L_000a: ldsfld string Reflector_Test.Program::output
    L_000f: ret 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is boilerplate code for executing a return statement, the compiler executes an unconditional jump to the last line, and loads the return value into a register before executing the `ret`. The JIT will optimise it better, I think the compiler doesn't bother doing any optimisations.

Comment: It does in Release mode, see my answer