# Superfluous NOPs and branches in unoptimized MSIL

Tags: c#, cil, il, ildasm, no-op

When I compile the following code as debug...

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myField;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myField; }
        set { myField = value; }
    }
}
```

...strange bytecode with seemingly useless instructions is produced by the compiler. For instance see what is generated for the getter of property `MyProperty` (disassembled with `ildasm.exe`):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance int32 
        get_MyProperty() cil managed
{
    // Code size       12 (0xc)
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init ([0] int32 CS$1$0000)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  ldfld      int32 MSILTest.MyClass::myField
    IL_0007:  stloc.0
    IL_0008:  br.s       IL_000a
    IL_000a:  ldloc.0
    IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method MyClass::get_MyProperty
```

Specifically, what is the `nop` at `IL_0000` doing there? And why does the compiler generate this useless `br.s` instruction at `IL_0008` literally out of nowhere? Why does it create  the temporary local variable `CS$1$0000`?

For a release configuration the instruction set is generated as expected though:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldfld      int32 MSILTest.MyClass::myField
IL_0006:  ret
```

---

**EDIT**

I think I've found an answer to the question why the branch and the temporary local variable is there in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675278/msil-superfluous-branch?rq=1): it's probably to easy setting break points during debugging. So the question that remains is why the `nop` instruction is genereated.

Comment: Non-optimized code is not optimized.  The NOP is there to be a target of a debugger breakpoint.  Removing redundant loads and stores produced by a recursive-decent parser requires a peephole optimizer.  Eliminating unnecessary locals is also an optimizer job.  The jitter itself can tackle these optimizations jobs without help from the compiler btw.

Comment: See also [Subtleties of C# IL codegen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/08/17/subtleties-of-c-il-codegen/), the first Google hit for "C# debug nop": _"With optimizations off, the C# compiler emits no-op IL instructions all over the place.  With debug info on and optimizations off, some of those no-ops will be there to be targets of breakpoints for statements or fragments of expressions which would otherwise be hard to put a breakpoint on"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler creates these opcodes to provide a better debugging experience. At the start of each of your c# lines the compiler will introduce a 
`nop` so the debugger can break there. The branch and the temporary local variable are emitted to let you analyse the functions return value.